# Good/Best/fast single algorithm for this situation. Half Superflip

Tags: rubiks-cube

How can I flip the edges in this picture in one algorithm if possible?

[image: here]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site, and please [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). You may want to clarify your question. What do you mean by flip?  Which edges are you talking about?

Comment: Well, surely OP must be talking about the edges that need to be flipped to solve the cube...?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 The question was edited. Originally it asked about flipping the edges in one move, rather than one algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want very short or even optimal solutions, you can use [Cube Explorer](http://kociemba.org/cube.htm). It can find optimal solutions for any cube position. This one can be done in 16 face moves, but no fewer.

R2 U' L F2 L' D' F' U2 D R D'F2 D L F L'

Answer (score 2):

Online solvers are cool, but it doesn't really help if you want to learn because computers solve differently than humans. You'd be better off learning algorithms that flow smoothly and are easy to remember.

The way I would solve your cube is by using 2 different edge flipping algorithms that are very easy to memorize and only use M and U moves.

So using your orientation with yellow on top and orange in front, you would use this algorithm that flips 4 edges on the top layer:

4 Edge Flip On "U" Layer:
M' U M' U M' U M' U' 
(Repeat this twice and all top edges will be flipped and your top layer will be solved.)

Now rotate your cube so that you have orange on the top and either green OR blue in front of you. Then you use this next algorithm which flips 2 opposite edges on the top layer.

2 Opposite Edge Flip On "U" Layer:
M' U M' U M' U M' U2 M' U M' U M' U M' 
(This algorithm looks long but it's really simple. You just do the first 7 moves, then do a U2 and repeat the same first 7 moves again.)

Also, both of these algorithms can be done extremely fast with some practice since they're only M and U moves and not something weird and slow using L, F, B and D moves in the same algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to find an algorithm, you could just let an online solver do it for you:

https://rubiks-cube-solver.com/solution.php?cube=0151214131212223222313234333414344444515555555666666666&x=1

The algorithm would be:

F U2 L2 F2 U' R2 D2 R' B' R L' U2 R2 L2 U B2 R2 U B2 D2

Answer (score 0):

Any of those algorithms would work:

Minimal amount of face turns:

```
 F  L2 F2 U  B2 R2 L' D' F' U2 F2 L' B2 U  D2 R   (16f*, 24q)
 F2 R' D  F' L' D  B  U2 D2 L' F  D' R' F  U  B2  (16f*, 20q)
 F2 U2 F  B2 D' L' D' F2 B  D2 F2 D' R  D  B  U'  (16f*, 22q)
 F2 U2 F  D' B' L' B  U2 B2 U2 D' B  R  B  U' D2  (16f*, 22q)
 R2 U' L  F2 L' D' F' U2 D  R  D' F2 D  L  F  L'  (16f*, 20q)
 R' F  R  D  F2 D' L  U2 D  F' D' R' F2 R  U' L2  (16f*, 20q)
 R' U' D2 B2 L  F2 U2 F  D  R2 L  B2 U' F2 L2 F'  (16f*, 24q)
 U  F2 U2 F' B2 D  R  D  F2 B' D2 F2 D  L' D' B'  (16f*, 22q)
 U  F2 U2 F' D  B  R  B' U2 B2 U2 D  B' L' B' D2  (16f*, 22q)
 U  B' R' B' U2 D  B2 U2 B' L  B  D  F' U2 F2 D2  (16f*, 22q)
 U  B' D' R' D  F2 D2 F2 B' D  L  D  F' B2 U2 F2  (16f*, 22q)
 U  D2 F2 U2 F' D  B  R  B' U2 B2 U2 D  B' L' B'  (16f*, 22q)
 U  D2 B' R' B' U2 D  B2 U2 B' L  B  D  F' U2 F2  (16f*, 22q)
 B  L  B  U2 D' B2 U2 B  R' B' D' F  U2 F2 U' D2  (16f*, 22q)
 B  D  L  D' F2 D2 F2 B  D' R' D' F  B2 U2 F2 U'  (16f*, 22q)
 B2 U  F  L' D' F  R' U2 D2 B  D  R' F' D  L' F2  (16f*, 20q)
 D2 F2 U2 F  D' B' L' B  U2 B2 U2 D' B  R  B  U'  (16f*, 22q)
 D2 B  L  B  U2 D' B2 U2 B  R' B' D' F  U2 F2 U'  (16f*, 22q)
```

**SOME** of minimal amount of quarter turns:

```
 F  R  L' U  F  D  R  U' D2 L  U  D' B  D' R' D' F' R' L   (20q*, 19f)
 F  R' F' R  L' F' U  B' U2 R' U2 R  U' B  U  F  L  U'  (20q*, 18f)
 F  R' F' R  L' U' F' U' B' L' U  R' L  U' R  F  B  L  U2  (20q*, 19f)
 F  R' U  F' R  F' B  D' R  D' B  L' U  L  F  B' D' R' L  D'  (20q*, 20f)
 F  R' U  F' R  D' F' B  D' R  L' B  U  B' L  D' F  D' R' L   (20q*, 20f)
 F  R' U' L' B' L' F' U  D' F  U' R  F  L  D  L  U  F' B  U'  (20q*, 20f)
 F  R' L  F' R  L' B' U' F' R' L' F  B' R  F' B  L  U  R  B   (20q*, 20f)
 F  U  F' U  R  U2 R' U' L' F' U  F  B' U' F' B  U  F  L   (20q*, 19f)
 F  U' F' L' F' U' F  B' U  F' B  U' F  L  U  R  U2 R' U'  (20q*, 19f)
 F  B' R  F  R  B  U  R  L' U' R' L  F' U' B' R' F2 B  U   (20q*, 19f)
 F  B' R  F' B2 L  B  D  F  R' L  D  R  L' D' B' L' B' U   (20q*, 19f)
 F  B' R  U  L  F  R2 L' U' R' L  F' R' F' L' U' F' B  U   (20q*, 19f)
 F  B' R' F' B  L' F' U' B' U' F  B' R' F' B2 U  F  L  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 F  B' R' U' R  F' D  L' D  F' B  L' B  U' L  B' D  R' L  D   (20q*, 20f)
 F  B' U  L  F  R  F  R  L' U  R2 L  F' L' U' R' F' B  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 F  B' U' L' D' L' F' R' U  F' U' D  F  L  B  L  U  R  F' U   (20q*, 20f)
 F  L2 B' R  F  U  R  B' R  B' D' L' D  F' D  B' U' F  L'  (20q*, 19f)
 F  D  R' D  L  U' D  L  F  R' L  F2 D2 B' D' R' U' B'  (20q*, 18f)
 F2 R' D  F' L' D  B  U2 D2 L' F  D' R' F  U  B2  (20q*, 16f)
 F2 B  L' B' U' F' R  L' U' R' L  U  B  L  F  L  F  B' U   (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  R  U  R' U  B  U2 B' U' F' R' U  R  L' U' R' L  U   (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U  F' B  U' F  B' U  F' R' U' L' U2 L  U  F' U  F   (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U  F' B2 L' F  B' U' B' U' F' R' F' B  L' F  B' U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U  B  U  R  U2 L  U  L' U' R' B' U2 F' U' R' U'  (20q*, 18f)
 R  F  U  B  U  R  L' B  L  B' U2 R' F' B' L' U  R' L  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U  B  U2 B' U' R  U' R' F' R' U' R  L' U  R' L  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U  B  U' B' U2 F' U' R' U' L' F' U  F  U  L  U2  (20q*, 18f)
 R  F  U  B  U' L  U2 L' U2 B' U  F' R' L  F' L' F  U'  (20q*, 18f)
 R  F  U2 R  B' R' F' B  U' R' U' L' F' U  F  B' U' B  L   (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U2 B  U  R  U  R' B' U' F' U' R' U2 L' U' L  U   (20q*, 18f)
 R  F  U' F' U' R' U2 L' F' U' B' U  B  U2 F  U  L  U   (20q*, 18f)
 R  F  U' F' B  U  F  B' U' F' R' F' U' F  U' L' U2 L  U   (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U' F' B  U  B' R' L' F' U2 L' B  L  F  B' U  L  U   (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U' F' B  U  B' L' U' R' U' F  B' R' F' R  U2 B  L   (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U' R  B' R' F' B  R' U  L' U2 B' U2 B  U' L  U   (20q*, 18f)
 R  F  U' R  L' B' R' L  F' R' U' L' U' R  L' B' R' L2 U   (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  U' B  U2 L  U2 L' U  B' U' F' R' U  F' L  F  L'  (20q*, 18f)
 R  F  B  L  U2 F  R' F' R  L' U' F' U' B' L' U  R' L  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  B  L  U' R  L' U  R' B' U' F' U' R' L  F' L' F  U2  (20q*, 19f)
 R  F  B' R  B  R' U  F' R' U' L' U  B' U2 B  U2 L  U'  (20q*, 18f)
 R  F' U  R' L' B2 R' L' U  R' U' D  B  D  R' L' F  D  L'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  U  F  U  F' R' U' L' U' F' U2 B' U' B  U  F  L  U2  (20q*, 18f)
 R  U  F  U  B  R  U' R' U' B' U2 F' R' U' L' U  L  U2  (20q*, 18f)
 R  U  F  U  B  R  U' R' L  U  L' F' B' R' U2 F' L  F  L'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  U  F  U2 B  R  U  L  U' L' U2 R' U' B' U' F' R' U   (20q*, 18f)
 R  U  F  U2 B  U  B' U' F' R' U2 L' U' F' U' F  L  U   (20q*, 18f)
 R  U  F  B' R  B  R' U2 F' R' L' B' U  F' B  U' F  L  U   (20q*, 19f)
 R  U  R' U' L' F' U2 B' U' L' U' L  B  U  F  U  L  U2  (20q*, 18f)
 R  U2 R' U' F  U' F' L' F' U' F  B' U  F' B  U' F  L  U   (20q*, 19f)
 R  U2 R' U' L' F' U  F  B' U' F' B  U  F  L  F  U  F' U   (20q*, 19f)
 R  U2 B  U2 B' U  R' U' L' F' U  L' B  L  F  B' L  U'  (20q*, 18f)
 R  U2 B  U' F  R' L  F  R  F' U  L' F' U' B' U  R' U2  (20q*, 18f)
 R  U' R' U2 L' U' F' U' B' L' U  L  U  B  U2 F  L  U   (20q*, 18f)
 R  U' B  U  F  L  U' F  R' F' R  L' F' U  B' U2 R' U2  (20q*, 18f)
 R  U' B  U2 B' U2 R' U  L' F' B  L' B' L  U' F  L  U   (20q*, 18f)
 R  B  U2 L  F' L' F  B' U' L' U' R' B' U  F' B  U' F  L   (20q*, 19f)
 R  B  U' F  B' U  F' R' U' L' U' F' B  L' B' L  U2 F  L   (20q*, 19f)
 R  L2 B  R' L  U  L  U  R  F  R  L' B  R' L  U  F' R' U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  L' F  D  R  D  B' U' D  L' U  D2 R' D' F' U' R' L  F'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  L' U  R' F' B' L' U2 B' R  B  R' L  U  B  U  F  L  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  L' U  R' B' U' F' U2 F  U  R' U  R  B  R  U  R' L  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  L' U  R' B' U' F' U' R' L  F' L' F  U2 R  F  B  L  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  L' U  R' L  U' R  F  U  B  U2 B' U' R  U' R' F' R' U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  L' U  R' L  U' L' F' L' U' L  U' B' U2 B  U  F  L  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  L' U  L  B  U' R' L  F' R  L' B' L' U' R' U' R' L  F' R   (20q*, 20f)
 R  L' U  L  B  L  U  L' U  F  U2 F' U' B' L' U  R' L  U'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  L' B  R' L  U  B  D  L  U' D2 R  U  D' F  D' L' D' B'  (20q*, 19f)
 R  L' B  L' U  B' L  D' F  B' D' R' L  F  U  F' R  D' B  D'  (20q*, 20f)
 R  L' D  F' B  L' U' L  B' D  R' D  F  B' R' F  U' R  F' D   (20q*, 20f)
 R  L' D  F' D  L' B  U' B' R' L  D  F  B' D  R' F  U' R  F'  (20q*, 20f)
 R  L' D  B' R  U' B  R' F' B  D  R' D  F' L  U' L' F  B' D   (20q*, 20f)
 R2 U' L  F2 L' D' F' U2 D  R  D' F2 D  L  F  L'  (20q*, 16f)
 R2 B2 R' L  D' B  R  D' R  D' F  B' L' B  D' R  U  B   (20q*, 18f)
 R' F  R  F' U  L' F' U' B' U  R' U2 R  U2 B  U' F  L   (20q*, 18f)
 R' F  R  F' U2 L' F' B' R' U  R  L' U' L  B  U  F  U  L   (20q*, 19f)
 R' F  R  L' U  R  U  L  B  R' L  F  R  L' U  B' L' U' R' L   (20q*, 20f)
 R' F  R  D  F2 D' L  U2 D  F' D' R' F2 R  U' L2  (20q*, 16f)
 R' F  U' B' D  F' D  R' D' B' L  B' L  U  F  L  B' R2 F   (20q*, 19f)
 R' D  F  R' L' D  B  U' D  L' U  R' L' B2 R' L' U  F' L   (20q*, 19f)
 R' D2 L2 F  B' L  F  U' D  F  D  B' D  R' L  U' B' D'  (20q*, 18f)
 U  F  R' F' R  L' U' F' U' B' L' U  R' L  U' R  F  B  L  U   (20q*, 20f)
 U  F  B' R  F  R  B  U  R  L' U' R' L  F' U' B' R' F2 B   (20q*, 19f)
 U  F  B' R  F' B2 L  B  D  F  R' L  D  R  L' D' B' L' B'  (20q*, 19f)
 U  F  B' R  U  L  F  R2 L' U' R' L  F' R' F' L' U' F' B   (20q*, 19f)
 U  F  B' U' L' D' L' F' R' U  F' U' D  F  L  B  L  U  R  F'  (20q*, 20f)
 U  F2 B  L' B' U' F' R  L' U' R' L  U  B  L  F  L  F  B'  (20q*, 19f)
 U  F' U  F  R  F  U  F' B  U' F  B' U  F' R' U' L' U2 L   (20q*, 19f)
 U  F' B  U' R' F' L' F' R  L' U' R' L2 F  R  U  L  F  B'  (20q*, 19f)
 U  F' B  L  F  B' R  F  U  B  U  F' B  L  F  B2 U' F' R'  (20q*, 19f)
 U  F' L  F  R  L' F  U' B  U2 L  U2 L' U  B' U' F' R'  (20q*, 18f)
 U  F' L  F  R  L' U  F  U  B  R  U' R' L  U  L' F' B' R' U   (20q*, 20f)
 U  F' L  U  R  B  R  F  U' D  F' U  L' F' R' D' R' U' F  B'  (20q*, 20f)
 U  R  F  R  U  R' U  B  U2 B' U' F' R' U  R  L' U' R' L   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  F  U  B  U' B' U2 F' U' R' U' L' F' U  F  U  L  U   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  F  U2 B  U  R  U  R' B' U' F' U' R' U2 L' U' L   (20q*, 18f)
 U  R  F  U' F' U' R' U2 L' F' U' B' U  B  U2 F  U  L   (20q*, 18f)
 U  R  F  U' F' B  U  F  B' U' F' R' F' U' F  U' L' U2 L   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  F  U' F' B  U  B' R' L' F' U2 L' B  L  F  B' U  L   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  F  U' R  B' R' F' B  R' U  L' U2 B' U2 B  U' L   (20q*, 18f)
 U  R  F  U' R  L' B' R' L  F' R' U' L' U' R  L' B' R' L2  (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  F  B  L  U' R  L' U  R' B' U' F' U' R' L  F' L' F  U   (20q*, 20f)
 U  R  U  F  U  F' R' U' L' U' F' U2 B' U' B  U  F  L  U   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  U  F  U  B  R  U' R' U' B' U2 F' R' U' L' U  L  U   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  U  F  U2 B  R  U  L  U' L' U2 R' U' B' U' F' R'  (20q*, 18f)
 U  R  U  F  U2 B  U  B' U' F' R' U2 L' U' F' U' F  L   (20q*, 18f)
 U  R  U  F  B' R  B  R' U2 F' R' L' B' U  F' B  U' F  L   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  U  R' U' L' F' U2 B' U' L' U' L  B  U  F  U  L  U   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  U2 R' U' F  U' F' L' F' U' F  B' U  F' B  U' F  L   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  U2 R' U' L' F' U  F  B' U' F' B  U  F  L  F  U  F'  (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  U2 B  U' F  R' L  F  R  F' U  L' F' U' B' U  R' U   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  U' R' U2 L' U' F' U' B' L' U  L  U  B  U2 F  L   (20q*, 18f)
 U  R  U' B  U  F  L  U' F  R' F' R  L' F' U  B' U2 R' U   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  U' B  U2 B' U2 R' U  L' F' B  L' B' L  U' F  L   (20q*, 18f)
 U  R  L' U' R' B' R' U' R  U' F' U2 F  U  B  R  U' R' L   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  L' U' R' L  U  R  F  R  U  R' U  B  U2 B' U' F' R'  (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  L' U' R' L  U  L' F' U' B' U2 B  U  L' U  L  F  L   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  L' U' L  F  B  R  U2 B  L' B' R' L  U' B' U' F' R'  (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  L' U' L  B  U  F  U  R' L  F  R  F' U2 L' F' B' R'  (20q*, 19f)
 U  R  L' U' L  B  U  F  U2 F' U' L  U' L' B' L' U' R' L   (20q*, 19f)
 U  R2 L' B' R' L  U' R' U' L' F' R  L' B' R' L  U' F  L   (20q*, 19f)
```

In other words, I agree with Diminished's answer. Shortest algorithms suggested by computers are never helpful.